# validation loss higher only for some tasks

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, multitasking

I am training a multi task network, it seems that the validation loss is higher than the training loss only for some tasks but for others, the network seems to converge pretty well. For one task in particular, the validation loss is much higher than the training one and it affects the average. I added some data augmentation, normalization, dropouts, batch norm etc. to avoid overfitting in general. How can I handle this one single task???

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you focusing on that single task. Try to study the residuals (regression) or the errors in classification (in case you are working with a classification). Without more info in the problem I cannot help you more than that!

Comment: Thanks, sorry, yes I am aware it is a bit broad. It is a classification problem with 6 tasks. Can you let me know what you mean by studying the errors in classification though? Do you mean I should try to profile when the network fails to correctly classify?

Comment: Yes! Exactly that! It can be very interesting to see the confusion matrix for that particular task. Also study the features of that class compared with the features of the rest of the classes. Do you know what I mean?